# Java Long Polling: Separate Thread?

Tags: java, long-polling

Because of browser compatibility issues, I have decided to use long polling for a real time syncing and notification system. I use Java on the backend and all of the examples I've found thus far have been PHP. They tend to use while loops and a sleep method. How do I replicate this sort of thing in Java? There is a `Thread.sleep()` method, which leads me to...should I be using a separate thread for each user issuing a poll? If I don't use a separate thread, will the polling requests be blocking up the server?

Comment: Do you really want long polling (or) You are ok with something like reverse-ajax (comet)?

Comment: I'd really like to implement my own lightweight service, so comet it out. But yes, basically reverse-ajax.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Update]
First of all, yes it is certainly possible to do a straightforward, long polling request handler.  The request comes in to the server, then in your handler you loop or block until the information you need is available, then you end the loop and provide the information.  Just realize that for each long polling client, yes you will be tying up a thread.  This may be fine and perhaps this is the way you should start.  However - if your web server is becoming so popular that the sheer number of blocking threads is becoming a performance problem, consider an asynchronous solution where you can keep a large numbers of client requests pending - their request is blocking, that is not responding until there is useful data, without tying up one or more threads per client.

[original]

The servlet 3.0 spec provides a standard for doing this kind asynchronous processing.  Google "servlet 3.0 async".  Tomcat 7 supports this.  I'm guessing Jetty does also, but I have not used it.

Basically in your servlet request handler, when you realize you need to do some "long" polling, you can call a method to create an asynchronous context.  Then you can exit the request handler and your thread is freed up, however the client is still blocking on the request.  There is no need for any sleep or wait.

The trick is storing the async context somewhere "convenient".  Then something happens in your app and you want to push data to the client, you go find that context, get the response object from it, write your content and invoke complete.  The response is sent back to the client without you having to tie up a thread for each client.

Comment: Ok the way I always assumed it was done is to send an ajax request and keep it open to the user, then run a loop inside the class on the backend and respond to the request when a response is available. Are you suggesting that I don't have an open ajax request?

Comment: See update.  My point is that you can keep the request open for each client without necessarily tying up a thread.  But you can certainly tie up a thread in a loop if you want to.

Comment: I'll have to look into it. This will probably be my accepted answer. Thank you.

Comment: What type of mechanism is used to search that blocked response and then access and return it with appropriate data?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure this is the best solution for what you want but usually if you want to do this at period intervals in java you use the [ScheduleExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html). There is a good example at the top of the API document. The [TimeUnit](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html) is a great enum as you can specify the period time easily and clearly. So you can specify it to run every x minutes, hours etc

Comment: I don't think this would work well in this situation though. Its not necessarily something that needs to be executed in timed intervals. Instead its like...while database returns no results...keep checking sort of thing.